# Android: HttpURLConnection redirects - probably cached

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have problem with HTTP calling, when I have multiple redirects and multiple calls. Lets have following code:

```
con = (HttpURLConnection) (new
URL("http://server/?function=auth/fetch_internal_ip")).openConnection();
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
con.setReadTimeout(1000);
con.connect(); StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
is = con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
buffer.append(line).append("\r\n");
is.close();
con.disconnect();
is = null;
ip = buffer.toString().trim();
```

For first using works perfectly, but for any other in the future are not redirects followed. Only reinstall of app or restart phone helps.

Where could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);` : this disables redirects globally for the following connections, you must remove this line if you want redirects.

Comment: Oh... Stuping mistake. I am looking on code for hours and this line dont seee. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but if you have a problem with your requests being cached you could try to use con.setUseCaches(false)

Comment: Hello, thank you. Here is more info. When I use function above for first time, redirets are followed. But only for first time. For any other cases I got content from first server, but not from last redirected page.

Comment: Can you update the post with a url that can actually reproduce the problem? It'd make it easy for others to test what is going wrong.